# Is there any way in which we can identify which users are registered with which device in azure notification hub for sending notification?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-notificationhub, azure-sdk-.net

How to find out which device is registered for which user for sending apple native notification?

I am getting all the devices registered in my notification hub with:
`var allRegistrations = await _hubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);`
but this has no information about the users.

Comment: You can make use of tags for that. Get the devicetag in app.component.ts 
const deviceTag = await Device.getId()
;and store it in the database along with the user information.

Answer (score 1):

To establish which user is linked with a certain registration, utilize the `UserInformation` attribute of each `NotificationHubRegistration` object.

```cs
var allRegistrations = await hubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync();
foreach (var registration in allRegistrations)
{
if (registration.UserInformation != null)
{
// User is registered with this registration
}
}
```

If you need to identify the device linked with each user, you may record the registration ID and device ID for each user in a dictionary or other data structure. The registration ID may then be compared to the list of devices registered to the notification hub to locate the appropriate device.

Comment: It doesn't work. I am not able to access registration.UserInformation, it has error "Registration Description does not contain a definition for UserInformation".

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of tags for that. Get the devicetag in app.component.ts

```
const deviceTag = await Device.getId() ;
```

and store it in the database along with the user information. That way, if you want to send notifications to particular user, you can get the device tag from the database of that user and send notification to that particular user.

```
 await _notificationService.SendNotificationAsync(deviceTags, notification);
```